# How to automatically readjust "Final frame of the playback range"?

Tags: animation

How to automatically readjust "Final frame of the playback range" to frame of last yellow dot in the Action Editor?

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more what you want to have? maybe a small example or a sketch with annotations?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QqAdmyu
You can see that yellow dots are not at the end.
How I can readjust final frame to last yellow dot without manually typing it to the field?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it is possible what you want, but you can check your "Set end frame" settings in your preferences -> keymap.

[image]

Then the end frame will be set at that position, where the cursor is, if you press that button - combination:

[image]